# Difference between NUnit vs NUnit2

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

I have NUnit 3.0 installed in my VS2015 and when I want to generate new test there are two options:
- NUnit
- NUnit2

What's the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, NUnit refers to NUnit 3.

Would recommend using NUnit 3 (a.k.a. NUnit!) if you are starting afresh. NUnit 2 is no longer updated for the most part, v3 has a number of new and useful features.

I agree it's not so clear! I raised an issue to change this: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-vs-testgenerator/issues/10

Comment: I suspected answer like that. Yeah, it's not clear at all. Thanks for the information! :)